# comparar campo actual con el siguiente para realizar una subquery en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una query, en ella, tengo una subquery, y solo quiero realizar la ejecución de la subquery siempre cuando el campo codigo actual no se repita con el siguiente.

Mostraré un seudocodigo sql para que se entienda lo que deseo hacer, especialmente en el CASE:

```
SELECT 
   @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS nro,
    0 AS 'Encab', 
   pa.codigo, 
   pa.partida,      
CASE 
WHEN pa.codigo = pa.codigo siguiente THEN '' 'aqui deseo comparar el pa.codigo actual con el siguiente'
ELSE 
(SELECT SUM(presupuestosa.valor + presupuestosa.valorm) FROM presupuestosa  
WHERE presupuestosa.obra=18
AND presupuestosa.empresa=1 AND presupuestosa.codigo=pa.codigo)   
END AS tvalor
FROM presupuestosa pa , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE pa.obra=18
AND pa.empresa=1 ORDER BY codigo ASC,Encab DESC,partida ASC
```

He tratado realizar esta solución colocando indicadores a los codigos repetidos, pero no me ha resultado. Desde ya, gracias.